# Checking user exists or not in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there any mysql command to check whether the given user is there in the mysq.user table or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User='username';
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try for Count

```
Select count(*) from mysql.user WHERE User='username';
```

if user not exist then return you 0 else they will return the number that how many time user exist.If it exist 1 time then give you 1,if 2 times exist then give you 2 and so on...
Hop it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there it is 
Use :

```
Select * From mysq.user WHERE user_id ='id ';
```

you can use username or id to check the users